# python script see traceback when running as background

Tags: python, linux

I have a python script running like this on my server:

```
python script.py &
```

The script works fine, but constantly I'm adding new things to the script and re-running it, somedays it runs for days without any problem, but sometimes the script stops running (**Not** running out of memory), but since I started the script as background I have no idea how to check for the Exception or error that cause the script to stop running. I'm on a Ubuntu server box running in Amazon. Any advice on how to approach this inconvenience ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use something like this.  It will dump the exception which caused termination to your syslog, which you can see by examining `/var/log/syslog` after your script has stopped.

```
import traceback
import syslog

def syslog_trace(trace):
    '''Log a python stack trace to syslog'''

    log_lines = trace.split('\n')
    for line in log_lines:
        if len(line):
            syslog.syslog(line)

def main():
    # Your actual program here

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        main()
    except:
        syslog_trace(traceback.format_exc())
```